# Recursive function to display all subsets of a set using bitmask c++

Tags: c++, recursion, set, bitmask

I am trying to write a recursive function to display all possible k-element subsets of an n-element set using bitmasks.

So far I have this code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void combinations(int *, int, int, int,int c);

int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    int k = 3;
    int bitMask[5] = {0};
    combinations(bitMask,0,n,k,0);

}

void combinations(int* arr, int start, int n, int k,int c)
{
    if(c==3)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout<<arr[i];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }else
    {
        for(int i = start; i < n; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = 1;
            combinations(arr,i+1,n,k,c+1);

        }
    }
}
```

However my output is :

```
11100
11110
11111
11111
11111
11111
11111
11111
11111
11111
```

Can someone give me some guidelines on how to change the function in order to get a result like this

```
11100
11010
11001
10110
10101
01110
01101
01011
00111
```

Thanks in advance, I am still bad with recursion.

The code below works perfectly.

```
  #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    void combinations(int *, int, int, int,int c);

    int main()
    {
        int n = 5;
        int k = 3;
        int bitMask[5] = {0};
        combinations(bitMask,0,n,k,0);

    }

    void combinations(int* arr, int start, int n, int k,int c)
    {
        if(c==3)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                cout<<arr[i];
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }else
        {
            for(int i = start; i < n; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = 1;
                combinations(arr,i+1,n,k,c+1);
                arr[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How could you ever expect there to be a zero in indices `[0,1,2]`, when you first fill them with ones and then never replace them with zeroes? Or in any other position for that matter, after you reach `c==3` and continue filling the array with ones.

Comment: Thank you very much. Added one line of code after the recursive call and now it works perfectly. You are awesome!

Comment: It seems you expect a result not suitable to the task conditions. You are asked to print all possible subsets of length 3 from a set of length 5, therefore expected result must list 3-element sets, but you typed 5-element sets, that look like permutations.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to

```
    arr[i] = 0;
```

after the return from the recursive `combinations()`.